# How to use primeng dropdown?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7

I used the "select" for the dropdown. Below is the coding.

```
<div class="ui-grid-col-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select name="status" formControlName="purchaseOrderStatusId">
          <option>Select PurchaseOrderStatus</option>
          <option *ngFor="let PurchaseOrderStatus of allPurchaseOrderStatus" value="{{ PurchaseOrderStatus.id }}">
                 {{ PurchaseOrderStatus.code }}
          </option>
        </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here all values from the API are saved in the variable **allPurchaseOrderStatus**.

And I want **id** as my stored value and **code** as the display value.

I need the same concept using the primeNg component.

Comment: Can anybody help me??

Comment: @Angle please check my answer it will help you to add dropdown in your app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like below code to replace `PrimeNG` dropdown with your existing one.

**Step 1: Import DropdownModule in your component.**

```
import {DropdownModule} from 'primeng/dropdown';
```

**Step 2: Add Dropdown in your html:**

```
<p-dropdown [options]="PurchaseOrderStatus" [(ngModel)]="selectedPurchaseOrderStatus" optionLabel="code">
```

So in `selectedPurchaseOrderStatus` you will get selected order object and you can get id like `selectedPurchaseOrderStatus.id`.

You can also use `OnChange` event to get selected options.

```
onChange()
```

> event.originalEvent: Browser event
>
> event.value: Selected option value
>
> **Callback to invoke when value of dropdown changes.**

for more example check below link of Dropdown in PrimeNG.

[PrimeNG Dropdown](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown)

Hope this will helps.

Comment: Thank you.. Here what you mean by "selectedPurchaseOrderStatus" .Is that the variable which saved all Api values. Let me know that.                                                                                               
 And  here where we write the dispaly value and stored value??

Comment: I am new in angular. Kindly give me a explanation ??

Comment: `selectedPurchaseOrderStatus` object where any selected values stores. and `PurchaseOrderStatus` is your array where you store api response.

Comment: Display & stored value will take automatically from your provided array.

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to create one array in your TS file having label and value field.
something like this:

```
PurchaseOrderStatus=[
 {label:'code1',value:'id1'},
 {label:'code2',value:'id2'},
 .....
]
```

here, in label field, you need to assign it **code** because label field will be used as the display value in the dropdown and in the value field, you need to assign it **id** as it will be used as the stored value of that particular option.

and in HTML file

```
<div class="ui-grid-col-6">
      <div class="form-group">
       <p-dropdown [options]="PurchaseOrderStatus" [(ngModel)]="selectedOrders" [filter]="true"></p-dropdown>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: PurchaseOrderStatus=[
 {label:'code1',value:'id1'},
 {label:'code2',value:'id2'},
 .....
]I think the code1, code2... u mentioned is the values which want to display in the dropdown. But all the values which I get is from the Api and all the values I stored in the variable "allPurchaseOrderStatus". Its not possible to write the all values in the ts file

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown as per this doc for using primeng dropdown you need to create this type of JSON array so for that you need to extract those values from "allPurchaseOrderStatus" variable using for loop and add it to the other array and then you can use it for your dropdown.